# Group by hour for each day and get all records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have few requirements to analyze data from  table below,

```
SELECT MId,SId,PId,DataHour,
 CAST(t.[SDate] as DATE), MAX(t.Powers) as PeakPower
 FROM [HourData] t  where CONVERT(date,[SDate]) between 
 CONVERT(date,'2016-12-01 09:45:59.240') and CONVERT(date,'2016-12-08 09:45:59.240')
 GROUP BY MId,SId,PId, CAST(t.[SDate] AS DATE),DataHour 
 order by  CAST(t.[SDate] AS DATE),DataHour,PeakPower
```

He above query will get sum of all MId,SId,PId for each hour in a day.
But I few other requirements, I need which PId has most used in an hour for each day i.e from the data link http://ideone.com/IW4FUA 
I need the data of most used PId for each hour like below.

```
 Power      PId
 5163.316   6
 5135.371   6
```

PId 6 has highest value for hour 0 and hour 1 in the day.
The sum of all pid in each datahour and get the max hour of it for each day.

This query will give details for each hour data

```
 SELECT MId,SId,PId,DataHour,
 CAST(t.[SDate] as DATE), MAX(t.Powers) as PeakPower
 FROM [MonataHourData] t  where CONVERT(date,[SDate]) between 
  CONVERT(date,'2016-12-01 09:45:59.240') and CONVERT(date,'2016-12-08   09:45:59.240')
 GROUP BY MId,SId,PId, CAST(t.[SDate] AS DATE),DataHour 
 order by  CAST(t.[SDate] AS DATE),DataHour,PeakPower

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HourData](
  [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
  [SId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
  [PID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
  [Powers] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
  [DataHour] [int] NOT NULL,
  [StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL)
```

Comment: What data type is the SDate column?

Comment: StartDate is SDate, Its Datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, here are some of them:

rextester link to test them all on your data: http://rextester.com/KBO56228

```
--declare @from datetime = '2016-12-01 09:45:59.240';
--declare @thru datetime = '2016-12-08 09:45:59.240';
/* the above can be simplified to: */
declare @from date = convert(date,'2016-12-01 09:45:59.240', 121);
declare @thru date = convert(date,'2016-12-08 09:45:59.240', 121);
```

**cross [apply](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)** version:

```
select distinct
      x.Mid
    , x.Sid
    , x.Pid
    , t.DataHour
    , Date = convert(date, t.SDate)
    , x.Powers
  from HourData t
    cross apply (
      select top 1
          Mid
        , Sid
        , Pid
        , Powers
        from HourData c
        where convert(date, c.sdate) = convert(date, t.sdate)
          and c.DataHour = t.DataHour
        order by c.Powers desc
       ) as x;
```

**[top with ties](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option)** version:

```
select top 1 with ties
      t.Mid
    , t.Sid
    , t.Pid
    , t.DataHour
    , Date = convert(date, t.SDate)
    , t.Powers
  from HourData t
  where convert(date, sdate) >= @from
    and convert(date, sdate) <  @thru
  order by row_number() over (partition by convert(date, t.SDate),t.DataHour order by t.Powers desc);
```

**[common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)** with **[row_number()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** version:

```
with PowerRN as (
select 
      t.Mid
    , t.Sid
    , t.Pid
    , t.DataHour
    , Date = convert(date, t.SDate)
    , t.Powers
    , rn = row_number() over (partition by convert(date, t.SDate),t.DataHour order by t.Powers desc)
  from HourData t
  where convert(date, sdate) >= @from
    and convert(date, sdate) <  @thru
)
select Mid, Sid, Pid, DataHour, Date, Powers
  from PowerRN
  where rn=1
  order by Date, DataHour;
```

`max()` **[over()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)** version:

```
with PeakPower as (
  select 
        t.Mid
      , t.Sid
      , t.Pid
      , t.DataHour
      , Date = convert(date, t.SDate)
      , t.Powers
      , PeakHourPower = max(t.Powers) over (partition by convert(date, t.SDate),t.DataHour)
    from HourData t
    where convert(date, sdate) >= @from
      and convert(date, sdate) <  @thru
    group by 
        t.Mid
      , t.Sid
      , t.Pid
      , convert(date, t.SDate)
      , t.DataHour
      , t.Powers
)
select Mid, Sid, Pid, DataHour, Date, Powers
  from PeakPower
  where Powers = PeakHourPower
  order by Date, DataHour;
```

`inner join` version:

```
select 
      t.Mid
    , t.Sid
    , t.Pid
    , t.DataHour
    , Date = convert(date, t.SDate)
    , t.Powers
  from HourData t
    inner join (
      select 
          DataHour
        , Date = convert(date, t.SDate)
        , PeakHourPower = max(t.Powers) 
        from HourData t 
        where convert(date, sdate) >= @from
          and convert(date, sdate) <  @thru
        group by 
            convert(date, SDate)
          , DataHour 
       ) as x on x.Date          = convert(date, sdate)
            and x.DataHour      = t.DataHour 
            and x.PeakHourPower = t.Powers

  where convert(date, sdate) >= @from
    and convert(date, sdate) <  @thru;
  order by t.Date, t.DataHour;
```